# How to disable Saving State on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

Wondering if there is a way to switch off the new "saving state..." feature of Android Virtual Devices (AVD); so that they will quit immediately and not spend a few seconds preserving a state.

Answer (score 40):

1. Go to **AVD Manager**
2. Click on pencil icon named as **Edit this AVD** for the AVD you want to make changes
3. A new window opens, click **Show Advanced Settings** on the bottom left of the window
4. In the expanded panel, under **Emulated Performance**, select **Cold boot** for the **Boot option**.
5. Select **Finish**.

[image]

Comment: @AlejandroRosas no it hasn't, please click on **Show Advanced Settings** to find the option

Comment: @AlejandroRosas please have a look at: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#dependencies and see if your machine meets the requirements.

Comment: many thanks! Was a new machine and the HAXM wasn't installed :')

Comment: @SnehPandya mine looks the same as Alejandro's, and KVM is available:

$ /usr/local/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -accel-check
accel:

0

KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.

accel

Comment: This is not an exact answer to the question.

Comment: Go to Tools > AVD Manager